# Using label to indicate which pages should have watermark in xwatermark pages

Tags: errors, watermark, xwatermark

`\newwatermark` command in `xwatermark` package has an option `pagex` which allows to to insert the watermarks only on selected pages. However, it requires me to put hard-coded page numbers for example.

`\newwatermark[pagex{42,56},angle=45,xpos=0,ypos=0,textmark=WRONG]{}`

I want to use labels and pageref to avoid hardcoding.

`\newwatermark[pagex{\pageref{l1},\pageref{l2}},angle=45,xpos=0,ypos=0,
 textmark=WRONG]{}`

where *l1* and *l2* are labels defined in the document.

Unfortunately, this complains with the following error:

```
**Missing number, treated as zero.**
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\pageref{...}` is a non-expandable macro, i.e. `TeX` can't reduce it to the real page number as such that's why the `pagex={\pageref{foo}}` command must fail, which expects literal numbers.

The package `refcount` provides the `\getpagerefnumber` macro which will return the literal number (i.e. it is expandable)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xwatermark}



\begin{document}
\newwatermark[pagex={\getpagerefnumber{foo},\getpagerefnumber{foobar}},angle=45,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Hello World!}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Foo} \label{foo}
\blindtext[10]

\section{Foobar} \label{foobar}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]